# Error activating keyboard in ionic view 3

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have the following problem, my apk, made in ionic 3, when it is already compiled, the main screen is displayed like this.

[image]

Everything is fine, but when I activate the taclado to write.

[image]

And I go back to the main screen this happens

[image]

As you may notice, the screen is cut off, as it is lost. I have no idea why this happens, anything helps me, Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Open the manifest.xml from the platform/android folder and in the main activity tag replace the android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" attribute with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
also try adding below in config.xml
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are a genius